# Can I use EJBs for I/O operations, thread management or HTTP requests?

Tags: java, ejb

Can someone clarify which of these scenarios can be done when implementing EJBs and if not which would be the appropriate solution?

1. Read Write a File within a EJB method.
2. Send via Socket or HtttClient a POST/GET HTTP request and manipulate its response.
3. Start threads within a EJB (Asynchrounous requests).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the EJB 3.1 Spec

"An enterprise bean must not use the java.io package to attempt to access files and directories in the file system"

Also

"The enterprise bean must not attempt to directly read or write a file descriptor.
Allowing the enterprise bean to read and write file descriptors directly could compromise security."

Answer (score 0):

> Read Write a File within a EJB method?

Yes, why shouldn't that be possible unless some file system restrictions are in place?

> Send via Socket or HtttClient a post/get request and manipulate its response.

That's normally done by either using a servlet or a webservice.
With EJBs you can also do remote calls, e.g. by looking up the remote interface using JNDI and invoking methods on it.

> Start threads within a EJB (Asynchrounous requests).

Yes and AFAIK with Java EE 6 you'd just have to add the `@Asynchronous` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks a **hell** like a homework to me, so I'll try to encourage you to at least show *"some"* effort and find the answers yourself as all your questions are *"Programmatic restrictions"* for EJBs. These restrictions can be found in EJB specification [here](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/ejb-3.1-pfd-oth-JSpec/ejb-3_1-pfd-spec.pdf), *Chapter 21 - Runtime Environment*.